# Remove all items with the same domain in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following array:

```
array = [
    'javi@indaloymedia.com',
    'caroline@grupoplatinum.com'
]
```

Then I have the following file:

```
javi@indaloymedia.com
asdsd@indaloymedia.com
jasdasd@indaloymedia.com
caroline@grupoplatinum.com
asdasde@grupoplatinum.com
wata@man.com
```

How can I do to eliminate all the elements that are in the array with domain 'indaloymedia.com' and grupoplatinum that is to say so that the file is as follows:

```
wata@man.com
```

Comment: Can you share your code and explain why it didn't solve your issue?

Comment: First process the array to extract the domain names you wish to filter.  Store them in a `set`.  Then read the file, writing only those lines that are not in the `set`.

Comment: use list comprehenseve `array = [x for x in array if not x.endswith('indaloymedia.com') and not x.endswith('grupoplatinum.com')]`

Comment: it doesn't help me because if I added another domain for example juan@meramira.com I would have to put it back in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
blacklist = [
    'javi@indaloymedia.com',
    'caroline@grupoplatinum.com'
]

domains = [e.split('@')[-1] for e in blacklist]

filtered_emails = []
with open("emails.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      domain = line.split('@')[-1]
      if domain not in domains:
        filtered_emails.append(line.strip())

print(filtered_emails)
```

Note that this solution won't cover every corner case, but should be enough to get you started.

https://repl.it/repls/RealDramaticField

Also, if your blacklist is huge, `domains` should be a `set` instead of a `list` for fast lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Only using basic for loops and an if statement:

```
def remove_domains(addresses, blacklist):
    for a in addresses:
        for b in blacklist:
            if b in a:
                addresses.remove(a)
    return a
```